# MoreTypes class not found

Tags: java, gradle, dagger-2, dagger, gradlew

I have a java project that is using dagger-2 and grpc, when I try to build it using ./gradlew build I get the following error:

```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/auto/common/MoreTypes
```

is MoreTypes supposed to be provided inside of dagger-2 dependencies or I should provide that dependency on the class path?

this is the relevant parts of gradle.build file content:

```
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.10"
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.1"
    id "java"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-all:1.5.0'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14'

    testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14'

   }



apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem in Dagger 2.14 fixed in 2.14.1. See [issue 994](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/994), "Dagger 2.14 breaks build":

> I have not isolated the issue to a small sample project at this point, but a possible cause I see is below, maybe that gives a pointer. I don't have any explicit dependency on Google Auto libs in that part of the build.
>
> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/auto/common/MoreTypes
> ```

Confirmed fixed in 2.14.1, which contains [this commit](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/635ac91c8e79fe268374175102377f1fa5193f55).